# Make doesn't work for Erlang 5.7.4 on Solaris?

Tags: erlang, opensolaris

Has anyone managed to build Erlang on OpenSolaris? Every time I try I get:

user@opensolaris:~/otp_src_R13B03# make clean
make: Fatal error in reader: Makefile, line 94: Badly formed macro assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to pretend to know anything about Erlang, but if you are running Solaris and getting Makefile problems it's a good bet that trying gmake could help out... (because many Makefiles out there end up using GNU-specific features, possibly without even noticing)